# Fundamentally, what information exists in the process of a malicious UEFI NTFS driver deleting a file that can be prevented by another driver?

Tags: c++, delete-file, ntfs, uefi

I'm interested in the complicated problem of stopping a rootkit at ring -2 ([System Management Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode)) from deleting a specific file. Even including formatting a drive would make this question too broad, so I'm specifically asking about deletion. Not forensic deletion either, standard file deletion. I'm trying to keep the question narrowed down to "what mechanism is used and can it be detected?"

Obviously, it'd be nice if system admins would keep cold storage backups, but any pen tester will point out how few business owners are willing to enforce best practices. So this is a question of "Is it possible to code a program to protect users when they won't protect themselves?"

A higher level method like the Windows API's [DeleteFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilea?) would involve system calls we can detect and modify, but I imagine that system system call is what then asks the *driver* to do whatever it does. I'm not asking specifically how, or all the ways, I'm just looking for a clue in the right direction towards researching: Is it possible for one driver to prevent another from deleting a file from a drive.

As a backup plan, I have an idea to use a pass-through tap that analyzes a SATA connection at the hardware level and prevents deletion / overwrite of a specific file, or sends out 2FA before allowing it. I'm just curious is that's overkill and there fundamentally exists a way to do this with a driver. This is irrelevant to the question, but just an example of how this *can* be done outside of code.

Fundamentally, what information exists in the process of a malicious UEFI NTFS driver deleting a file that can be prevented by another driver?

I've been studying malware analysis for years now, but rootkits are a new area, hence the naive question here. I may need to access my own UEFI drivers and just disassemble the driver and look for myself. I can't seem to find any documentation. If I understand correctly, SATA is a *standard*, NTFS is a *standard* and therefore there should be some *standard* instructions used by firmware to perform file deletion.

My question here is mostly aimed at avoiding wasting my time. If I can find standard instructions used by Windows UEFI drivers to perform file deletion over SATA / NTFS, but there's no way to effectively detect or intercept those instructions by another driver, then it's a waste of time reverse engineering the firmware.

*Maybe* the more fundamental question I should be asking is: "Can one driver (conditionally) prevent another driver (at the same privilege level) from executing *any* instruction?"

Comment: but what is ring -2 ?

Comment: where you need ring 0 or may be 1-2

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Ring -2 is System Management Mode. I linked to it.